# How to do operations based on a group in R

Tags: r, sorting, quantile

I have a data frame that I created as a sample

```
 v<-data.frame( g= c(sample(1:10, 8)))
 g<-data.frame( v= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

 df<-cbind(g,v)
 df_s <-df[order(df$g,df$v,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

The g column is a group of common values, lets say dates.  I want to sort per each g the values in descending order and then put them into quintiles or really n-tiles.
I had the code

```
df_s <-df[order(df$g,df$v,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

to sort it but the output is not coming in order expected, see below.  I want

```
1,v high
1,v mid
1,v low
2,v high
2,v mid
2, v low
```

Instead I get this.

```
v  g
8 2 10
2 1  9
5 2  8
3 1  6
7 2  5
4 1  4
6 2  2
1 1  1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please revisit the question. where is that v, and (low, high, med) coming from?

Comment: @Ananta I would assume that it is just to show how the values should be ordered

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
 df[order(df$v, -df$g),]
```

In the OP's code, by using `decreasing=TRUE`, it gives a different order

```
 order(df$g,df$v,decreasing=TRUE)
 #[1] 3 5 2 6 1 4 7 8
 order(df$g,-df$v)
 #[1] 8 7 4 1 6 2 5 3
```

It would have been better to use `set.seed` to make the example reproducible.

Comment: Thanks.  the order I guess with decreasing=TRUE isn't doing it as cleanly as the -df$v.  Now based on the values sorted, how would i put them into quartiles .  None of the functions seem to have a place for a group variable to create unique quartiles based on a category.

Comment: @jazz_learn It is bad practise to ask multiple questions in a single post.  I answered your `order`ing problem.  It is better to ask the quartile as a new question.